# Showing form data in a block

Tags: forms, 8, blocks

I have a multi step custom made form in Drupal 8.2.x.

Some of the user input from the form needs to be shown on a separate block.

The following code worked fine for users that are logged in:

```
$tempstore = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('mymodule_name');
$tempstore->set('my_variable_name', $some_data);
```

But it doesn't work for anonymous users on my site.

Is there a tempstore for anonymous users that works site wide that I just haven't discovered yet?

Answer (score 2):

you should use session manager for storing current sessions for anonymous users

private_tempstore gives us a temporary store that is private to the current user

refer to this link asked some days ago [session storage for anonymous users](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/197576/storing-data-session-for-anonymous-user)