# Set and read data in session between anonymous and authenticated user

Tags: 8, users, sessions, cookies

On my Drupal 8 site, when an anonymous user "A" visit this link: `https://www.example.com/page-1?data=12345678`, I want to store the `data` value in a session and save it later to the user account under `field_user_data` when this same user "A" login/signup to the site.

**Note:** The query `data` will be unique for every single user and will not be used twice ever.

I thought the best way to go is by using the data value in a session and use it later when the same anonymous user becomes authenticated on the site.

So on site load and when user "A" is using the site as anonymous, I am saving the data value in a session using:

```
// Get query values from url.
$request_query = Request::createFromGlobals();
$data = $request_query->query->get('data');

// Save the "$data" in a session variable.
$tempstore = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('my_module');
$tempstore->set('data', $data);
```

and later, in another php file but within the same module, when the anonymous user "A" authenticate to the site, I am saving the session value to his user account as shown below:

```
// Get 'data' Session value
$tempstore = \Drupal::service('user.private_tempstore')->get('my_module');
$data = $tempstore->get('data');

// Set 'data' value to user account.
$authenticated_user->set('field_user_data', $data);

// Save
$authenticated_user->save();
```

**The problem is `$data` session is shared between all users and not being unique per user** while `$data` value must be unique for every single user.

What is wrong with my code ?
Using cookies will be a better approach for my use case ?

**Update #1:**

Using above code to store sessions or using the method provided here https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/246268/88628, both are working as expected but in only one case (For authenticated users)

When an authenticated user visit `https://www.example.com/page-1?data=12345678` (where `12345678` will be unique per user), both above methods are working as expected and the value `12345678` is indeed saved to the authenticated user account under `field_user_data` field.

However, when User "A" visit `https://www.example.com/page-1?data=12345678` as anonymous user and then later decided to login/signup, both above methods are not working for me!

**Note:** For now I am using `cookies` by using `setcookie('data', $data, 0, '/');` and `$data = $request->cookies->get('data');` and it is working for both anonymous & authenticated users.

But I would really prefer to get it done using sessions !

Comment: Maybe this is what you want: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/246268/66659

Comment: The referenced question does not answer my question, please check the **Update #1:** section in the question. Thank you

Comment: BTW your code is not using session data and cookie data will get you in more trouble when you deploy this in production. You should use `\Drupal::request()->getSession()` as explained in the linked topic, which usually works well for anonymous and logged in users.